# PYTHON Calculating Laplacian of Gaussian Kernel Matrix

Tags: gaussian-kernel

I've been trying to create a LoG kernel for various sigma values. But the problem is that I always get float value matrix and I need integer value matrix as it is published on every document. I haven't find a method.

**1st image:** My functions and my output

**2nd image:** My expected matrix

[image: Here is my function and my result]

[image: Expected output matrix]

Comment: “integer value matrix as it is published on every document”. A LoG needs floating-point weights. You can scale it and round the values, but it will no longer be a proper LoG. The image you show is not a proper LoG. You also need to create a larger kernel that a 3x3. Use for example `2*ceil(3*sigma)+1` for the size. If you want to be more precise, use 4 instead of 3.

Comment: “integer value matrix as it is published on every document” means "I want to create the matrix below"

Comment: Don’t expect to create that using `exp` or anything related to a Gaussian. You can simply copy those weights if you want to reproduce what the paper does, but know that that is not a LoG!

Comment: The answer you are looking for in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2445994/discrete-laplacian-of-gaussian-log

You need to scale the matrix by multiply with -16/calculate(0, 0, sigma)